# Android Gridview Animation not working in final item

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I have a GridView with 12 elements arranged in a 3x4 grid.  Each element is a layout called grid_item.xml containing an ImageView and a TextView underneath it.  Initially the ImageView is the image of a tile.  When you click/touch any of the GridView elements an animation is applied to the ImageView to scale it down and reveal the TextView underneath.

This all works fine except for the final (bottom right) element in the GridView.  When I click on it (in the Android emulator, haven't tested on a device) the click event (called grid_click) is called but the "onAnimationStart" listener is not called (it *is* called when I click any other GridView element).

In other words, when I click the bottom right GridView element there's no animation and I see this in Logcat:

TEST start animation

However, if I click any other element the animation works fine and in Logcat I see:

TEST start animation

TEST onAnimationStart

Logcat doesn't output anything else to indicate a problem.  If anyone can help I'd appreciate it as I've spent a couple of days trying to figure this out.  My code is as follows:

```
private void init_gridview()
{
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setNumColumns(3);
        gridview.setColumnWidth(32);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                grid_click(position,v);
            }
        });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return(3*4);
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // inflate grid_item.xml and return a View combining textview and imageview
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View MyView = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) 
            {  
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            }
            else
            {
                MyView=convertView;
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
            tv.setText("something");

            ImageView iv = (ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            iv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.tile);

            MyView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(32,32));
            return(MyView); 
    }
}

private void grid_click(int position, View v)
{
    View clicked_view=v;

    Animation scale_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_down);

    scale_down.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
    {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
        {
            Log.i("TEST","onAnimationStart");
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });

    Log.i("TEST","start animation");
    ImageView iv2 = (ImageView)clicked_view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    iv2.startAnimation(scale_down);
}
```

Here is the scale_down.xml animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromXScale="1" android:fromYScale="1" android:toXScale="0" android:toYScale="0" android:duration="250" />
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="180" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:duration="250" />
</set>
```

Here is the layout for each item in the GridView, called grid_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:src="@drawable/tile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"  
    android:textSize="17sp"  
    android:shadowColor="#555555"
    android:shadowDx="1.0"
    android:shadowDy="1.0"
    android:shadowRadius="1.5"
    />   
</FrameLayout>
```

Finally the main layout containing the GridView, called game.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <GridView 
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="106dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the gridview change the

```
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Never use wrap_content as layout height for gridview.